# How to implement SlidingMenu.OnOpenedListener correctly?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, back-button, slidingmenu

I want to hide back button when sliding menu is opened, otherwise to show it

How should I implement SlidingMenu `OnOpenedListener`?

I use [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) SlidingMenu with [ActionBarSharlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution, for those who are interested in.

Set `OnOpenedListener` and `OnClosedListener` to your `SlidingMenu` object

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
```

- To show back button (sliding menu is closed)

  ```
  menu.setOnOpenedListener(new OnOpenedListener() {

              @Override
              public void onOpened() {

                  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
              }

          });
  ```
- To hide back button (sliding menu is opened)

  ```
  menu.setOnClosedListener(new OnOpenedListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClosed() {

                  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
              }

          });
  ```